# How to Create 2D arrays in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

i have followed this previuos thread
[How to manage 2d array in Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095907/how-to-manage-2d-array-in-smalltalk)
but it did not helped me please help me out .

I am trying to create NXN array and then print them out .
for exmaple 2x2 array : what am i missing ?

```
|testArr|.

testArr := (Array new: 2)
at: 1 put: ((Array new: 2) at: 1 put: '0'; at: 2 put: 'X');
at: 2 put: ((Array new: 2) at: 1 put: 'P'; at: 2 put: 'Y').

1 to:2 do:[:a|

1 to:2 do:[:b|

Transcript show: testArr at:a at:b.
].
].
```

THE ERROR IS AT  Transcript with unknow selector . what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm asking because your code smells as if you were using some data structure instead of modeling first class objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

First the error message you describe. I guess in full length it says:

> MessageNotUnderstood: ThreadSafeTranscript>>show:at:at:

So this means you should set some parenthesis to get the right messages to the right objects. Try:

```
Transcript show: ((testArr at:a) at:b).
```

Now there is an issue with your Array assignments too.

In Smalltalk/Pharo/Squeak, if you send `at:put:` to an array it returns the object you assigned, the second parameter of `at:put:`, not the receiver. So in your example the variable `testArr` doesn't contain an array of arrays, but the string 'Y'.

If you really want to use message cascading with `;`, you must send the `yourself` message to the array at the end of your cascade.

Like this:

```
testArr := (Array new: 2).
testArr at: 1 put: ((Array new: 2) at: 1 put: '0'; at: 2 put: 'X'; yourself).
testArr at: 2 put: ((Array new: 2) at: 1 put: 'P'; at: 2 put: 'Y'; yourself).
```

Comment: Man you are genius i'm breaking my head with this OO Language.

Comment: Give yourself a break. It takes time, grasshopper ;) But will repay you in spades if you take the time to "get it"...